# open a existing tab of safari in ios programmatically

Tags: ios

I want to reopen / redirect to existed tab which is opened in safari from my ios native objective c Code. Can any one please help on this.

Thanks 
djrecker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On UIWebview, use javascript `window.close();` after that you can reopen using `window.open()`.